# What is the most efficient way to redirect requests?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, asp-classic

I'm modernizing a legacy ASP.NET site with a bunch of classic ASP content.  There are a few dozen `asp` and `aspx` pages that are just redirects:

```
'this is a file called Something.aspx
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<% Response.Redirect("/Something/Default.aspx", true) %>
```

These files are littered throughout the app, and I want to delete all of these files and consolidate this redirection logic in a single table somewhere:

```
From,To
/Something.aspx,/Something/Default.aspx
/sub/SomeOtherThing.asp,/overhere/NewVersion.aspx
...
```

Then, in the Application_BeginRequest method, I figured I'd check this table and if the incoming request matched a `From` entry, I would do the redirect.  But this seems really inefficient, because then every single request would incur the overhead of that table lookup.

I've also considered letting the missing file request cause a 404 error, and *then* do the lookup and redirect, so the overhead only hits a much smaller number of requests, but that seems a little kludgy.

So the question is: what's the best (or reasonably efficient) way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Rewrite Map feature of URL Rewrite to handle redirection.

```
<rewriteMap name="MyRewriteMap">
  <add key="a.html" value="b.html" />
  <add key="c.aspx" value="d.aspx" />
  <add key="e.php" value="f.php" />
</rewriteMap>
```

Alternatively you can implement an HttpModule to handle the redirects. Load the mapping from your data store and cache it for future requests. Then check the request URL of any 404 errors against the mapping. Handling only the 404 errors is more efficient than checking every request.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on IIS7 (or later)?  If you are you could just install the url rewrite module and put all your redirects in web.config

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module